# Can't put circular layer that surrounds imageView on different iPhone devices

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, layer

[image]

How can I fix this issue?
The image is set with constraints in the storyboard; the other circle is set with these lines of code:

```
let centerY = profileImage.center.y+20+(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height)!
let centerX = profileImage.center.x
let center = CGPoint(x: centerX, y: centerY)
let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: (profileImage.frame.width/2)+2, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi-CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: CGFloat.pi/2, clockwise: true)
trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
trackLayer.strokeColor = Functions.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#3859B9").cgColor
trackLayer.lineWidth = 3
trackLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
view.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
```

On iPhone 7 (the one on the right) seems to be right.

Comment: In which function are you adding the circle? Most probably your code is called before the layout is done. Btw you can also add Autolayout constraints programatically to the circle you create programatically.

Comment: your code in did load method?
then you can use dispatch queue with 0.5 delay

Comment: Why don't you add sublayer to profileImage it self ?

Comment: Yes, my code is in viewDidLoad, is it wrong to put that there?

Comment: Put it in viewWillAppear

Comment: If I put that in viewWillAppear is the same

Comment: viewDidlayoutSubviews.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using fixed values for navigation's or status' bar height will lead to such errors. You should position your layer according to the image view. For that you can simply assign the frame of the image view to your layer:

```
trackLayer.frame = profileImage.frame
```

Since the layout may change for several reasons (e.g. device rotation), you should do this in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` of your view controller.

Since the frame of the layer is now smaller than in your example, you should create the center with:

```
let center = CGPoint(x: profileImage.bounds.midX, y: profileImage.bounds.midY)
```

Comment: But what should I put in the definition of UIBezierPath to replace the variable center?

Answer (score 1):

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    let centerY = profileImage.center.y+20+(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height)!
    let centerX = profileImage.center.x
    let center = CGPoint(x: centerX, y: centerY)
    let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: (profileImage.frame.width/2)+2, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi-CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: CGFloat.pi/2, clockwise: true)
    trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    trackLayer.strokeColor = Functions.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#3859B9").cgColor
    trackLayer.lineWidth = 3
    trackLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    view.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)

 }
```

OR in write the code in viewDidAppear without delay

Comment: Using delayed execution to force creation when the layout is computed is a very bad approach. You shouldn't do that. `UIViewController` has callback methods about layout has changed.

Answer (score 0):

This would fix the issue.

1. Add the `layer` to `profileImage.layer`.
2. `trackLayer.frame = profileImage.bounds`

---

Full code should be like this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let center = CGPoint(x: profileImage.bounds.midX,
                         y: profileImage.bounds.midY)
    let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    trackLayer.frame = profileImage.frame
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                                    radius: (profileImage.frame.width / 2) + 2,
                                    startAngle: -CGFloat.pi - CGFloat.pi / 2,
                                    endAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2, clockwise: true)
    trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    trackLayer.strokeColor = Functions.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#3859B9").cgColor
    trackLayer.lineWidth = 3
    trackLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    profileImage.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using interface builder:

1. Drag UIView and drop above the imageview
2. Change view custom class to CirculerProgressView
3. Set center X and Y constraints with imageview center
4. Set height and width constraints(greater then imageView height & width)

   ```
   @IBDesignable class CirculerProgressView: UIView {

               override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
                   return CAShapeLayer.self
               }

               override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
                   super.draw(rect)
                   setupLayer()
               }

               private func setupLayer() {
                   let trackLayer = layer as! CAShapeLayer
                   let center = CGPoint(x: frame.width/2, y: frame.height/2)
                   let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: frame.width/2, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi-CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: CGFloat.pi/2, clockwise: true)
                   trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
                   trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
                   trackLayer.lineWidth = 3
                   trackLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
                   trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
               }}
   ```

Comment: Since you're using a layer for drawing, you shouldn't update it in `draw(rect:)`. You should either update it in `layoutSubviews` or drawing directly in `draw(rect:)` with `circularPath.stroke()`. Your code shouldn't change much.